# mongodb update is updating multiple records

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to update  one record but it is updating multiple reports.

```
count = mycol.count_documents({"structure.values.unique_report_name": report_name})

mycol.update_one(
    {
        # "unique_report_id": 151154,
        # "structure.name": "somwmmwmw",
        "structure.values.unique_report_name": report_name
    },
    {
        "$set": {
                "structure.$[].values.$[].report_data": data
        }
    })
return JsonResponse({"msg": "success"}, safe=False)
```

Something is wrong in $set part .
Please take a look what can be the issue

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6232ebabaeb8d039c736e07f"),
        "structure" : [
            {
                "name" : "My folder",
                "values" : [
                    {
                        "report_name" : "my report",
                        "report_heading" : "my report",
                        "background" : "#f0f2f5",
                        "grid" : false,
                        "report_data" : "some",

                        "unique_report_name" : "myreport"
                    },
                    {
                        "report_name" : "report 2",
                        "report_heading" : "report 2",
                        "background" : "#f0f2f5",
                        "grid" : false,
                         "report_data" : "some",
                  
                        "unique_report_name" : "report2"
                    }
                ],
                "type" : 1
            }
        ],
        "unique_report_id" : 480966
    }
```

Added sample mongodata. Please take a look

Comment: Please show the sample collection document and also the data to be updated for better elaboration. Thanks.

Comment: added sample data @YongShun

Answer (score 0):

Use the `arrayFilters` and `$[<identifier>]` filtered positional operator to update the field for the nested document in the array.

```
db.collection.update({
  "unique_report_id": /* Report id */,
  "structure.name": /* Structure name */,
  "structure.values.unique_report_name": /* report name */
},
{
  "$set": {
    "structure.$[structure].values.$[value].report_data": /* Data */
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "structure.name": /* Structure name */
    },
    {
      "value.unique_report_name": /* report name */
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_613HkRySf5)

Pymongo:

```
mycol.update_one(
    {
        "unique_report_id": /* Report id */,
        "structure.name": /* Structure name */,
        "structure.values.unique_report_name": report_name
    },
    {
        "$set": {
          "structure.$[structure].values.$[value].report_data": data
        }
    },
    array_filters = [
      {
        "structure.name": /* Structure name */
      },
      {
        "value.unique_report_name": report_name
      }
    ]
)
```

Comment: raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Error parsing array filter :: caused by :: Expected a single top-level field name, found 'structure' and 'value', full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "Error parsing array filter :: caused by :: Expected a single top-level field name, found 'structure' and 'value'", 'code': 9, 'codeName': 'FailedToParse'}

Comment: got this error in pymongo

Comment: Did your `arrayFilters` is same as what I posted in the answer?

Comment: Yes, https://codeshare.io/AdvXNx check this link

Comment: Your `$set` should be `{ "structure.$[structure].values.$[value].report_data": data }`